# Adding httpclient DefaultRequestHeader and RequestMessage header

Tags: c#

Should I still add my headers to HttpRequestMessageif I already have add on my httpclient headers?
what is the difference of adding from httpclient first and then requestMessage?

like this:

```
 public static async Task<JsonDocument> ParseJsonData(string api, string method, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xml,application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(UserAgent);

        var uri = new Uri(api, UriKind.Absolute);

        var Method = new HttpMethod(method);

        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(Method, uri))
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            request.RequestUri = uri;
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Pragma.ParseAdd("no-cache");
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.Headers.Connection.ParseAdd("keep-alive");
            request.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd(UserAgent);
        
         switch (Method.ToString().ToUpper())
            {
                case "POST":

                    string loginInfo = "{\"login_id\": \"" + credential.username + 
                                    "\", \"password\": \"" + credential.password + "\"}";
                    using (var content = new StringContent(loginInfo, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"))
                    {
                        request.Content = content;
                        return await ResponseMessage(request, cancellationToken);
                    }

                case "GET":
                    {
                        return await ResponseMessage(request, cancellationToken);
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both collections are merged when sending a request. If there's a duplicate header, both will be sent out.

Comment: So, it's like the same if I put the header only either to httpclientdefaultrequest or httpreqeuestmessage?

Comment: where is the best to input my headers? because I'm very confused if I still need to put all of them

Comment: When you are making multiple requests, and you have some headers that need to go out for every request, use default headers.
When you are making a single request, or have headers that don't need to go out for every request, use per-message headers.

Comment: thank you for the information. so If I input the headers to defaultrequestheaders, I don't need to input under request header?